# How to add jquery validation for dynamically appended input text box

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I need validate the dynamically appended input text box for the below code

```
$("#btnadd").click(function() {
             // Made it a local variable by using "var"
            var addkey = document.getElementById("txtaddkey").value;
            if(addkey!=""){
                $('<li><span>'+addkey+'</span><span class=\"amountin\"><a href=\"#\">$0.05</a> $ <input type=\"text\" maxlength=\"5\"/></span><span class=\'close ui-icon \'></span></li>')
                    .find('.close').click(function (){
                        $(this).parent().remove();  
                    })
                    .end().appendTo('#keyword');
                $('#txtaddkey').val('');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might help [JQuery validate dynamically add rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819651/jquery-validate-dynamically-add-rules)

Comment: Thank you Aaron... As you suggested I have checking class name for dynamic input box validation.

Comment: @Elankeeran ~ Since it's not obvious to me how his answer helped you, perhaps either you or @AaronHathaway can spell out the obvious "look at this part" for the next person to come along who would be equally helped by this answer.

Comment: your link gives the idea to use class for validation rule. But  drachenstern your answer for common validation for jquery events.

Answer (score 1):

> How to add jQuery **anything handling** to a dynamically appended **element**

http://api.jquery.com/live/ - Live was designed for just this thing

Given an appended textbox of `<input type='text' id='mytextbox'></input>` then this would be helpful: ( **NOTE**: I recommend you add an ID to the textbox if it will only show up once, or else a useful classname if it will be added repeatedly ~ Update the selector below to reflect the ID or class)

```
$('#mytextbox').live('keyup', function(event){ 
  if ( $(this).val() == "fail value" ) {
    $(this).val() = "good value";
  }
});
```

It really depends on how you want to validate it. The initial question doesn't really show how you would validate it now, (unless I'm missing something)

Comment: I am looking for general form validation for validate the dynamic input text box on form submit but in your solution it will work only on key up cases.

Comment: @Elankeeran ~ I think you absolutely do not understand my example. I was offering `an example!` not a final solution. You could alter that to be `'keyup keydown keypress'` and get all three events, but how would you know which event you were handling? You _must_ read the jQuery api reference for this answer.

Comment: @Elankeeran ~ Also note that had you given me what you wanted to have for a validation (which you did not) I could have incorporated that into my answer. I suggest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask